# How do I get album id's from the Facebook graph api?

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am sending a request with the following url:  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/albums?

The response I am getting is

```
"data": [
{
"id": "X",
"from": {
"id": "X",
"name": "Robert S"
},
"name": "Profile Pictures",
"link": "LINK",
"cover_photo": "X",
"privacy": "everyone",
"count": 11,
"type": "profile",
"created_time": "2010-09-04T07:02:31+0000",
"updated_time": "2015-04-08T23:49:48+0000",
"can_upload": false
},
{
"id": "X",
"from": {
"id": "X",
"name": "Robert S"
},
"name": "Cover Photos",
"link": "LINK",
"cover_photo": "X",
"privacy": "everyone",
"count": 1,
"type": "cover",
"created_time": "2014-12-02T04:45:56+0000",
"updated_time": "2014-12-02T04:45:56+0000",
"can_upload": false
}
]
```

Notice how the id's are the same? I replaced the actual id with 'X' for demonstration purposes. It does this for every one of my photo albums.

How do I get unique id's for each photo album?

Comment: The `from` id should of course be the same, because that is your user id. But the “outer” ids shouldn’t be the same, but an individual one for each album – and according to my quick test, that is of course still the case with API v2.3. (If you get different results, then file a bug report.)

Comment: It's a bit odd that my album IDs are the same as my from IDs. Will try again and see if I get different results this time, but it might be a bug on their end.

Comment: Yeah, try I again. I would suspect that this was rather an error on your part – because if Facebook had messed this up somehow, it would affect a lot of apps, and so there should be public outcry about this in the developers group or the bug report tool, but I didn’t find anything current on this on either of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/albums?fields=id
```

It will return all albums ID